# JQuery Mobile header styling disappearing on a dynamically generated page

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile, dynamically-generated

I have a second page that is populated using data from an Ajax call on the home page. The header on this dynamically generated page is missing all its JQuery styling, and I suspect the two are related. This is my HTML for the page being generated:

```
<div data-role="page" id="breakdownDialog" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="header" id="cvResultsDialog">
            <h3></h3>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="dialogContent">

        </div>
    </div>
```

There is also some CSS styling I have used, which I think needs streamlining, but I don't think is causing the problem. This is because when I comment out this code the header is still missing the styling:

```
#cvResultsDialog {          
        width:100%;
        text-justify: distribute-all-lines;         
        }

#cvResultsDialog:after{
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
}

#cvResultsDialog > h3 {
             display: inline-block;
             display:inline;
             text-align="left";
            }

#cvResultsDialog span {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            text-align="right";
            }
```

I then populate the header (and the page) using the response from an Ajax call from the previous page. The page is populated on the click of a button (`#resultsList`) linking to this page:

```
$('#resultsList').on('click', '#cvResults', function() {
//find previous result that matches the filename on the link.
for(var i=0;i<storedResponses.length;i++){                  
    var currentTitle=storedResponses[i].title;
    var textClicked=$("h3",this).text();
    if(currentTitle===textClicked){
        currentResult=storedResponses[i];
    }
}
$('#cvResultsDialog h3').text(currentResult.title);
$('#cvResultsDialog span').text(currentResult.percentage);

//this last bit is populating the page, so is irrelevant for this question
$('#dialogContent').empty();
for(var i=0; i<currentResult.profile_json.length; i++){
$('#dialogContent').append(
            '<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing ="0" width="100%" style="border: 4px solid transparent;"><tr id="'+ 
            currentResult.profile_json[i].title+'"><td>'+
            currentResult.profile_json[i].id+'</td><td align="right">'+
            currentResult.profile_json[i].value+'</td></tr>'                            
        );
}

});
```

Finally here is a picture of the header. You'll notice it doesn't have the JQuery Mobile styling and the back button is missing.

[image: Header with styling missing]
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the back button, you need to apply the `data-add-back-btn="true"` to the header div not the page div.

```
<div data-role="header" id="cvResultsDialog" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ezw00m1t/)**

Other than that the header looks correct given the CSS styling you are applying... Perhaps you can tell us how you want the header to be arranged?